# React JS: adding a flex style to map components which is based on product data (simple Image slider)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I am currently learning and trying to build a ecommerce website, but I am stuck in the product page for a while. I am trying to add flex style to the map component that is from a certain data, but it seems like not working.

This is the map component

```
  const listItems = product_card.map((item) => (
    <div className="card" key={item.id}>
      <section className="card_Container">
        <div className="card_imgBox">
          <SimpleImageSlider
            className="card_img"
            width={400}
            height={300}
            images={item.thumb}
            showBullets={true}
            showNavs={true}
          />
          <div className="card_info">
            <h2>{item.product_name}</h2>
            <p>{item.description}</p>
            <p className="price">
              {item.price}
              <span>{item.currency}</span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  ));
```

And this is the scss for this component.

```
.card{
    background-color: aqua;
    .card_Container{
        // display: flex;
        // background-color: black;
        .card_imgBox {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            text-align: left;
            align-items: center;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            margin-left: 2%;
            padding-top: 20px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            background-color: bisque;
            .card_img {
                margin-top: 200px;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

The result always show me the boxed vertically instead of horizontally. Any helps would be appreciated

Comment: codesandbox link?

Comment: Try `flex-direction: row` for `.card_imgBox`

Comment: What is SimpleImageSlider?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-glade-dvps24?file=/src/Shop.scss

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a horizontal alignment you should use display:flex property for parent element or div

example:

```
<div className="listHolder">
product_card.map((item) => (
    <div className="card" key={item.id}>
     <p>Hello</>
    </div>
  ));
</div>
```

In Css file

```
.listHolder {
   display:flex
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the flex-direction from your imgBox as it will make the items appear vertically instead of horizontally. Also, if you tell us what items do you want to make them display flex, we can help you properly. Since there are many display flex in your code, it is really hard for us to figure it out?